# null value exception when entering into database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

i have created a table in a service based database to store the sales information.the table includes the columns date,time,name,purchase,quantity,cost(in this specific manner). the code for inserting into the table is

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\rnawa_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Random\Random\sales.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into salesTB (Date,Time,Name,Quantity,Cost) values ('"+date.Text+"','"+time.Text+"','"+txtName.Text+"','"+listBox1.Items.Count+"','"+ txtCost.Text+")";

foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into salesTB (Purchase) values ('" +item.Substring(0,10)  + "')";
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Clone();
conn.Close();
```

The `date.text` and `time.text` labels displays the date and time respectively.they are assigned their values in the form load event.
the `txtName.text` and `txtCost.text` labels get their values from previous form using constructor as

```
public Form2(ListBox.ObjectCollection objectCollection, string name,string total)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(objectCollection);
    txtName.Text = name;
    txtCost.Text = total;   
}
```

When I am executing this, it's giving me an error saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Cost'". And if I set allow nulls in the cost column in database then it show any other column name in the exception error.

Comment: User can Inject code through text fields to your database. **Bind parameters, don't concatenate SQL string**. Second you probably try to insert string 'NULL' to int/decimal field.

Comment: The first command text is never executed, the commands built during the loop are never executed except for the last one when you exit the loop.

Comment: Also you're inserting a new row each time when you do the foreach loop after the initial insert, so there's no relationship between the first insert and the second set of inserts. A better approach would be to keep your data normalised, and insert all data with each item.

Comment: You also should not be using the source database in your project for `AttachDbFilename`; that will wreck your source project and will not work when you try to deploy your app. Use `|DataDirectory|`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parameterised query to avoid the errors, since you're concatenating explicit string values. Also your logic is wrong, doing this will cause un-normalised data which will be horrid for any DB Admin to sort. I would consider using this instead:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\rnawa_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Random\Random\sales.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();

foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into salesTB (Date,Time,Name,Quantity,Cost,Purchase) values (@date, @time, @name, @quantity, @cost, @purchase)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("time", time.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", txtName.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("quantity", listBox1.Items.Count));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("cost", txtCost.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("purchase", item.Substring(0,10)));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Clone();
}

conn.Close();
```

It's not tested, but you get the idea.

Comment: thank you for the help. i get the idea about using parameterised queries. but from your above code i think it will add a new row in the table  for each item in the listbox. can you please show me how i can get all the item.substring values in the column of purchase.

Comment: also wrap the above in a using ;)

Comment: That's correct. Why would you want one row for the purchase, and then another completely unrelated row with NULLs showing just the purchase? It's not good RDBMS practice.

Comment: Again, although I understand what you want, I'd advise not to store comma delimited values in a column. A better way would be to store each item and it's cost in separate rows, then you can use a `VIEW` to write a query which will roll up this for you. The idea is that the more you drill down each item of each transaction the better, so if you need to go back and change a transaction later you can do this, because you have a normalised data model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nicer and safer way to do what your after:

```
      string SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO salesTB (Date,Time,Name,Quantity,Cost)" +
                            "VALUES (@date, @time, @name, @quantity, @cost)";

        using (SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection(cs.ToString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, DBConn))
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@date"].Value = date.Text;

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@time"].Value = time.Text;

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = txtName.Text;

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = listBox1.Items.Count;

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@cost", SqlDbType.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@cost"].Value = txtCost.Text

                DBConn.Open();
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DBConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you. the table contains one more column "purchase" where i want all the values present in the listbox. can you show me how i can do it?

Comment: `INSERT INTO salesTB (Date,Time,Name,Quantity,Cost,Purchase)"
                            "VALUES (@date, @time, @name, @quantity, @cost,@anythingyouwantPurchase)` Then  `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@anythingyouwantPurchase", SqlDbType.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@anythingyouwantPurchase"].Value = txtPurchase.Text;`

Comment: i want  ALL THE VALUES FROM THE LISTBOX. any list box function that i can use?

Comment: Pop this into its own method eg: `public void SaveItems(string pItem)` then you can use your foreach loop to do `foreach (string item in listBox1.Items) SaveItems(item);` you then can use this parametre in here `sqlCmd.Parameters["@cost"].Value = pItem.Substring(0,10)` this lets you insert into this table with another method