# SQL Injection Based on ""=""

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I'm new to SQL, so please bear with me (though I'll concede that maybe this is just a programmatic concept that I should have already grasped)...

A reading about possible SQL injection vectors suggested that one potential mode of attack would be to set a username or password field to `"or ""="`.

An example usage case would be:

```
uName = getRequestString("UserName");
uPass = getRequestString("UserPass");

sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ='" + uName + "' AND Pass ='" + uPass + "'"
```

Resulting in the following line of SQL code:

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ="" or ""="" AND Pass ="" or ""=""`

The reasoning they gave is that `WHERE ""=""` always evaluates to true. How and why is this so? I understand how `or 1 = 1` evaluates to true, but how does this code evaluate to true?

Your help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**:
I think my initial confusion stemmed from reading the double quotes as escapes, instead of empty strings. This should have been obvious, so thanks!

Comment: I am assuming you meant `'` and not `"` with my answer. I only know MSSQL and double quotes don't work that way there... maybe it's different in other versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you don't need this special edge case to inject on that query...

> The reasoning they gave is that WHERE `''=''` always evaluates to true. How and why is this so?

`''` is just an empty string constant. So, logically, `''` is equal to `''`. It's just like saying 1=1, since a constant will always equal itself.

Written out:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Users 
WHERE 
    (Name = '' OR '' = '') 
    AND 
    (Pass = '' OR '' = '')
```

Since it is an OR statement, only one of the conditions in each has to be true, BUT it has to be true in both clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to always check the varables if included in an SQL statment or as you said, will result in a crash:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uPass))
{ 
   // SQL STATMENT 
}
else 
{ 
   // ERROR ONE IS EMPTY 
}
```

also its best to bind those variables to parameters to avoid injection see my answer here on how to do that:

[null value exception when entering into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380524/null-value-exception-when-entering-into-database/32381005#32381005)